# "document" pode ser acessado em arquivo Javascript separado do HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

tenho um HTML com um arquivo Javascript vinculado. No Javascript eu tento acessar um elemento desse HTML através de document.getElementById("meuId") e está retornando Null.

Isso deveria acontecer?

No Javascript:

```
const formCadNot = document.getElementById("cadastrar-noticia")
```

No HTML:

```
<script src="js/cadastrarNoticia.js"></script>

...

 <form class="formulario" id="cadastrar-noticia" action="cadastraNoticia">
...
```

Obs: o caminho do script em "src" está correto. Dentro da pasta onde meu HTML está tem uma pasta "js" co o arquivo cadastrarNoticia.js

Comment: depende, onde tentou fazer isso? já havia carregado o documento html? tentou colocar o script no final do arquivo html?

Comment: Eu carreguei o script já no head do html. Ses eu coloco o script direto no HTML ele funciona. Mas eu quero ele num arquivo separado. Vai ficar muito script no index.html

Comment: @LucasPletsch Utilize o evento `window.onload` para executar o código após o carregamento da página.

Comment: isso acontece pq o documento ainda não foi carregado e já tentou acessar um elemento que ainda não estava do `document`. Coloque seu código dentro de um bloco que execute quando o documento estiver todo carregado, assim por exemplo: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){   seu código aqui });`

Comment: leia mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
se quiser, posso postar uma resposta comentando, mas acredito que deva ter algo assim já aqui

Comment: O valor de `formCadNot` será `NULL` ... pois o script foi disparado antes do elemento ser renderizado, só mudando o comportamento quando usado o atributo `defer=""` na tag `SCRIPT`. Pode-se usar o `window.onload`, ou `DOMContentLoaded` (este é semelhante ao defer pois não espera as imagens e nem outros recursos externos, apenas o documento), linkei no topo da sua pergunta tudo o que precisa saber sobre isto.

Comment: @RicardoPontual a tua dica resolveu melhor meu problema. Se quiser postar como solução, eu marco ela como solucionado daí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está carregando o seu script antes de carregar o elemento com o seu id. Sendo assim, no script você tentar obter um elemento que não existe.

A solução para este problema é importar o script abaixo do elemento ou então, criar uma função para ser chamada pelo evento `onload` quando a página for carregada.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function setColor() {
    const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    div.style.color = "#f00";
    div.innerText = "Texto colorido com o Javascript.";
}
```

```html
<body onload="setColor();">
    <div id="myDiv">
        Texto não colorido.
    </div>
</body>
```